# Hibernate One-To-One parent id in child is null

Tags: hibernate

i have a problem with the cascading in hibernate.

I got these 2 entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "testscenario")
public class Testscenario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, name = "scenario_id")
    Long scenarioId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "scenario", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Mapping mapping;
....

@Entity
@Table(name = "mapping")
public class Mapping {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, name = "mapping_id")
    Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "scenario_id", referencedColumnName = "scenario_id")
    private Testscenario scenario;
```

When i try to store the entities the parent id for the child entity stays null. This is how i store the entities:

```
Testscenario testscenario = new Testscenario();
testscenario.setName(scenarioName);
testscenario.setForwarder(forwarder);
Mapping mapping = new Mapping();
        mapping.setJar(mappingFileParam.getBytes());
        mapping.setJarFilename(mappingFileParam.getOriginalFilename());
        mapping.setSourceFormat("sourceFormat");
        mapping.setDescription("description");
        mapping.setTargetFormat("targetFormat");
        testscenario.setMapping(mapping);
testscenarioService.create(testscenario)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're not calling `mapping.setScenario(testscenario)`

Comment: do i have to call it after `testscenarioService.create(testscenario)` ?

Comment: i tried it but it is not working...

Comment: If a mapping can exist without scenario, you can call it after.